# Function with two "accept from pipeline" parameters

Tags: powershell

I want a function to allow me to pass in either a device ID or a display name, and to do stuff with it.

In the following example, I pass in a customer PowerShell object that only contains a device ID (`$obj.ID | Test-Function`), but both `$DisplayName` and `$Id` end up with that value.

How do I force the value into the correct parameter?

```bsh
function Test-Function {
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]
        [string]$DisplayName

        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]
        [string]$Id
    )
    Begin {
        #Code goes here
    }
    Process {
        Write-Host "displayname is: $DisplayName" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "displayname is: $Id" -ForegroundColor Green        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with [**ParameterSets**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878348(v=vs.85).aspx). Notice I also fixed a comma in your code and the `Write-Host` output:

```
function Test-Function 
{
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
            ParameterSetName='DisplayName'
        )]
        [string]$DisplayName,


        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
            ParameterSetName='Id'
        )]
        [string]$Id
    )
    Begin {
        #Code goes here
    }
    Process {
        Write-Host "displayname is: $DisplayName" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "Id is: $Id" -ForegroundColor Green        
    }
}
```

Lets give it a try:

```
[PsCustomObject]@{Id = "hello"} | Test-Function
```

Outputs:

```
displayname is: 
Id is: hello
```

and

```
[PsCustomObject]@{DisplayName = "hello"} | Test-Function
```

outputs

```
displayname is: hello
Id is:
```

Comment: I like this solution, very elegant. I see how it worked for you, but when I create a test object differently, it isn't working. I am using the New-Object cmdlet to create the object (`$props = @{Id = '1';DisplayName = 'server1'}; $object = new-object pscustomeobject -Property $props`) but when I run `$object.Id | Test-Function` I get _Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters._ It must be something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `ValueFromPipeline` and set $`false` for `Mandatory` attributes , so the correct solution is:

```
function Test-Function {
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$false,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]
        [string]$DisplayName,

        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$false,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]
        [string]$Id
    )
    Begin {
        #Code goes here
    }
    Process {
        Write-Host "displayname is: $DisplayName" -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host "displayname is: $Id" -ForegroundColor Green        
    }
}
```

Comment: This will allow you to invoke Test-Function without a parameter which is not not be intended. Beside that - your solution is working.

Comment: You're right. This test can be done in function or by using your answer ;)

Comment: Anyway a valid answer and it may fit better. thus upvoted.